# UIDatePicker crash: failing to allocate 100,000 rows

Tags: ios, uikit, uidatepicker

I'm getting a rare crash when using an iOS date picker.

The crash is: 
NSInternalInconsistencyException
Failed to allocate data stores for 100000 rows in section 0. Consider using fewer rows

```
UITextField *dateinput = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(26, yOffset, 268, 35)];
[dateinput setPlaceholder:@"Ends:"];
[dateinput setText:@""];
[self configureTextField:dateinput];
[footer addSubview:dateinput];
[self setDateinput:dateinput];

UILabel* dateinputLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(26, yOffset - 21, 268, 30.0f)];
[dateinputLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRGBHex:0x777777]];
[dateinputLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:11]];
[dateinputLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
dateinputLabel.text = @"End Date";
[footer addSubview:dateinputLabel];

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate]; //crash on this line
[dateinput setInputView:datePicker];
```

For some reason the date picker is internally allocating a huge number of rows and crashing because not that many rows are available.

Is it correct behaviour for the date picker to allocate so many rows? And if not, can anyone see what I'm doing that is causing this odd behaviour?

Note that I haven't been able to replicate this issue. It's clear that a small number of users are being affected (via crashlytics)

Comment: Did you try setting a minimumDate/maximumDate?
Why do you add the date picker as a input view of a text field?

Comment: Thanks @Andy I'll try setting a min/max date to see if that helps. I'm not totally sure why it's being set as the input view of a text field (this is a legacy project). You're quite right that this is also weird. I'll set min/max date and I'll make the date input direct instead of via a textfield.

Comment: Please file a bug, including a sample project that reproduces this issue.  `UIDatePicker` should not be crashing.  https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I'm getting this crash from customers too. It's while trying to allocate a viewController with a date picker in it and I can't reproduce it. The stack trace doesn't even hit the viewDidLoad method on the VC in question. I tried setting a min/max now as well so we'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: hi ,were you able to fix this bug??? even i am struck  with same bug.....